# Unity Cross platform mobile picker

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, cross-platform, picker

I wanted to do something (that I assumed was quite standard) in unity but I can't find much on it.

When the user first boots my app, I want to give them a "time picker" dial, so that they have a daily reminder to use the app.

I can't seem to find a generic, cross platform way to implement a time picker on android and iOS via unity (without using plugins, or building from scratch).

Do I just have to bite the bullet and do 2 implementations or is there a standard cross platform approach?

Thanks in advance!